# Find shortest distance between two sets of points on the map (large datasets)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have two sets of points in two separate tables like this :
t1 :
Point_1 |Lat | Long
..................
Point_n |Lat |Long
and
t2 :
Pt_1 |Lat | Long
..................
Pt_m |Lat |Long
with no relation between the two tables.
What would be the best way **(least resources)** to identify the top 3 closest points in t2 for each pt in t1, particulalrly when t1 and t2 are huge? Maybe Geohashing?
What I tried and seems to work fine with small datasets is :

```
t1
| extend blah=1
| join kind=fullouter (t2 |extend blah=1) on blah
| extend distance = geo_distance_2points(Long,Lat,Long1,Lat1)
|sort by spbldrom_code, distance asc
| extend rnk = row_number(1,point <> prev(point))
| where rnk<=3
|project point, pt, distance, rnk
```

Please pardon the sloppiness ; I'm learning .
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try reducing the data size on both sides of the join operator, by filtering out irrelevant or ill formatted rows and columns. Perhaps you can use geo_point_in_polygon\circle() to throw out irrelevant data.
2. Try using broadcast join or maybe shuffle join:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/broadcastjoin
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/shufflequery
3. You can use s2\geohash\h3 hashing functions in two ways:

   a. Per each table, combine nearby points into one representative point. The
   idea is to use hash cell central point as a representative for all
   points that reside in the cell. This will reduce tables sizes. Something like:

```
          datatable(lng:real, lat:real)
          [
             10.1234, 53,
             10.3579, 53,
             10.6842, 53,
          ]
          | summarize by hash = geo_point_to_s2cell(lng, lat, 8)
          | project geo_s2cell_to_central_point(hash)
```

b. Calculate hash value for each point and join on the hash value. Something like:

```
        let t1 =
            datatable(lng:real, lat:real)
            [
              10.3579, 53,
              10.6842, 53,
            ];
        let t2 =
            datatable(lng:real, lat:real)
            [
              10.1234, 53,
            ];
        t1 | extend hash = geo_point_to_s2cell(lng, lat, 8)
        | join kind=fullouter  hint.strategy=broadcast (t2 | extend hash = geo_point_to_s2cell(lng, lat, 8)) on hash
```

4. Perhaps partition operator might also speed up the query:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I really like 3.b as a good workaround to reduce the pairs of points to calculate inter-point distance, to a subset of relatively close-by points, instead of the entire set.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I think to be a better way to do this and want to share it.

- Firstly, the issue with tessellation / geo-hashing is this:
  Let's assume you have two sets of points with coordinates in two tables T1 and T2 and what to calculate the closest point in T2 for each point in T1. Now let's assume you have a point in T1 very close to the border of a geo-hash cell, and another point in T2 close to the same border, but in the neighboring geo-hash cell. Using the join method based on hash id, the algorithm will never calculate the distance between these two points, although they are very close, so the end result will miss this pair.
- A better way to do the join of the two tables to calculate inter-points distance is generating a join key based on truncated coordinates. So for each point in each table , we create this key based on the relevancy of interpoint distance (what is the max inter-point distance we care about).
  Example : for a point with coordinates ( 45.1234; -120.5678 ) the join key could be 25.1-120.6 (truncation and concatenation). With this rounding and using the join method , we would capture everything in table 2 within app 15 km radius of that point in table 1. Going for 25-120 as the join key will capture everything within 150Km.  This will reduce significantly the joined table and avoids the caveats of geo-hashing method.

At this point I'm better at writing prose than code :), however I hope what I described above it makes sense. It certainly works for my project while circumventing the resource problems (cpu/mem).

Answer (score 0):

Happy you've found a way that works for you. Another option that you may try is also taking into account neighbor cells.

H3 hash has such capability: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/geo-h3cell-rings-function

Something like this:

```
let h3_resolution = 8;
let t1 = datatable(lng1:real, lat1:real)
[
    40.75864778392896, -73.97856558479198,
    40.74860253711237, -73.98577679198793,
    40.741092676839024, -73.9902397446769,
];
let t2 = datatable(lng2:real, lat2:real)
[
    40.75594965648444, -73.98157034840024,
    40.766085141039774, -74.01798702196743
];
t1 
| extend hash = geo_point_to_h3cell(lng1, lat1, h3_resolution)
| join kind = inner (
    t2 
    | extend rings = geo_h3cell_rings(geo_point_to_h3cell(lng2, lat2, h3_resolution),1)
    | project lng2, lat2, hash_array = array_concat(rings[0], rings[1])
    | mv-expand hash_array to typeof(string)
) on $left.hash == $right.hash_array
| project-away hash, hash_array
| extend distance = geo_distance_2points(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2)
| project p1 = tostring(pack_array(lng1, lat1)), p2 = pack_array(lng2, lat2), distance
| sort by distance asc 
| summarize closest_3_points = make_list(p2, 3) by p1
```